# column names based on condition - export to CSV

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to do export to csv based on some response and functionality is working as expected. But here there are some column names I need to give conditional base that I'm not able to achieve. Here based on response i'm forming column names with data like this.

```js
  if(data.length > 0) {
       const items = [];
        data.forEach(line => {
              let csvLine = {
                Id: line.id,
                Qty: line.qty,
                Grade: line.grade,
                Veggie: line.veggie,
                Fruit: line.fruit,
              }
              items.push(csvLine);
            });
            
            this.exportToCsv('my_Report.csv', items);
      }
```

Here, the fruit and Veggie columns must adjust in accordance with user input.
I'll ask the user if they want a veggie or a fruit, but how do I make the csvLine form correctly? I can repeat the full csvLine here based on input, but I don't think that's the best solution. Help would be greatly appreciated. I'm grateful.

Currently Not Optimised way doing like this:

```js
 if(data.length > 0) {
       const items = [];
       if(input === 'Veggie') {
        data.forEach(line => {
              let csvLine = {
                Id: line.id,
                Qty: line.qty,
                Grade: line.grade,
                Veggie: line.veggie // Here removed Fruits
              }
              items.push(csvLine);
            });
       } else {
        data.forEach(line => {
              let csvLine = {
                Id: line.id,
                Qty: line.qty,
                Grade: line.grade,
                Veggie: line.veggie,
                Fruit: line.fruit,
              }
              items.push(csvLine);
            });
       }
       
            
            this.exportToCsv('my_Report.csv', items);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can define `Veggie` and `Fruit` as optional properties and add them **after** the instantiation of the object itself.

Optional properties can be declared with a `?`:

```
export interface Meal {
    Id: string;
    Qty: string
    Grade: string;
    Veggie?: string;
    Fruit?: string;
}
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
if(data.length > 0) {
    const items = [];
    
    data.forEach(line => {
        let csvLine = {
            Id: line.id,
            Qty: line.qty,
            Grade: line.grade,
        } as Meal; // I added this cast to 'Meal'

        if(input === 'Veggie') {
            csvLine.Veggie = line.veggie;
        } else {
            csvLine.Fruit = line.fruit;
        }

        items.push(csvLine);
    });
            
    this.exportToCsv('my_Report.csv', items);
}
```